# Extracting one list element from several lists in R

Tags: r, list, vector

I am working with the following loop in order to fit several models:

```
lambda = seq(from=0,to=10.2,by=0.2)
   for(i in lambda){
       assign(paste("fitb",i, sep=""), 
              lmmlasso(y = mydata.B$Bloodpress, 
                       x = x.matrix, z = z, grp = grp1,
                       lambda = i, pdMat = "pdIdent"))
}
```

So I ended up with a lot of model fits in lists named: fitb0, fitb0.2 and so on

I need to extract the AIC value from each list and put it together in a vector, instead of using a code as:

```
AIC=c(fitb0$aic, fitb0.2$aic ... fitb10$aic)
```

What could I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe grab the aic inside your loop?

```
lambda = seq(from=0,to=10.2,by=0.2)
i=1 ; aic=NA
   for(i in lambda){

              wholelassoresults=lmmlasso(y = mydata.B$Bloodpress, 
                       x = x.matrix, z = z, grp = grp1,
                        lambda = i, pdMat = "pdIdent"))
                       assign(paste("fitb",i, sep=""),wholelassoresults)   
                       aic[i]=wholelassoresults$aic

}
```

Comment: thank you! at the very beginning your code didn't give what I wanted, but after some few changes, it did!